# Logarithmic x-axis formatting for x-value lower than 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, axis, logarithm, ticker

I'm trying to format my x-axis to show logarithmic values below 1 correctly.

The x-axis starts at 0.15, and I would like to show the values as 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0,4 0.5 and so on....

Right now I'm using the following formatting:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, _: '{:g}'.format(x)))
```

which gives the following result:
[Log x-axis, wrong formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KefQM.png)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I did it the "dirty way" by simply using:

```
ax.set_xticks([0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200, 300])
```